# Send alert only for certain link texts being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I have a situation where I need to alert the user if a certain link text for a hyperlink is selected. This code simulates the scenario I'm trying to overcome. As the code runs right now, the alert occurs when any link text is clicked instead of just the links to Google. I can't seem to get the script to isolate on only the selected link text, is there any way of doing this? Thank you for any help you can give.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TESTING</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="c:\\users\\user\\desktop\\test2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
    </h2>
    <h3>
        <a href = "https://www.reddit.com/">Reddit</a>
    </h3>
    <h4>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
    </h4>
```

This is the script that I'm using to try and send the alert:

```
window.onload = find_link;

function find_link() {
    var stuff = $( "a:contains('Google')" );
        if (stuff) {
            onclick = notify;
        }
}


function notify() {
    alert('clicked');
}
```

Comment: I'm not good with regex so I can't make a answer, but what I would do is use get the link elements then use a regex to remove all but the google.com links. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the selector you're using:

```
var stuff = $( "a:contains('Google')" );
```

This returns an empty jQuery object, but that Object is itself truthy; it appears you're expecting it to return a Boolean, which it clearly does not.

You could rewrite your code, of course:

```
$( "a:contains('Google')" ).on('click', notify);
```

This doesn't need to be enclosed in a function, given that you're using jQuery you could either wrap it in the traditional `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a:contains('Google')").on('click', notify);
});
```

Or simply place it a `<script>` element that occurs just before the closing `</body>` tag, so that the various elements exist before the `<script>` is encountered and run.

References:

- [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thank you for your considerate answer. This helped me a lot! I've been starring at this for a few days now.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check on the object's length, otherwise it will always return *true*:

```
var stuff = $( "a:contains('Google')" ).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the next way with the jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('a:contains(Google)').on('click', () => {
        alert('Google link clicked');
    });
});
```

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/60dp8kc7/